# duplicate "a" tag depends on a number I get from api response

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

So, I'm still a beginner with Reactjs. I want to duplicate this "a" tag inside the ".menu" div depending on a number coming from the api response.

```
<div className="menu">
    <a onClick={this.targetValue} href="#">1</a>
</div>
```

if the quantity I'm returning from the api response like this

```
quantity: "3"
```

I want to duplicate the "a" tag 3 times like this and change the text content depending on its number

```
    <div className="menu">
        <a onClick={this.targetValue} href="#">1</a>
        <a onClick={this.targetValue} href="#">2</a>
        <a onClick={this.targetValue} href="#">3</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: OK, now what is your question? What have you tried? Where's your `render` method? Where are you fetching the resource and setting your component state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that JSX is still JavaScript (with a few bits on top).  So if you want to repeat something, you can just loop.  There are many ways to iterate in JS, here are a few.

[For loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration):

```
render() {
  const links = [];

  // Loop the number of times your API dictates
  for (step = 0; step < 5; step++) {
    // Create a link for each number
    // You want to add the `key` property to each child when iterating
    links.push(<a key={step} onClick={this.targetValue} href="#">{step + 1}</a>)
  }

  return (
    <div className="menu">
      {links} {/* render your links */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

[Nicer array method](https://yang-wei.github.io/blog/2015/09/14/initialize-an-array-with-fix-length-in-javascript/):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="menu">
      {Array(5).fill(null).map((_, index) => (
         <a key={index} onClick={this.targetValue} href="#">{index + 1}</a>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Lodash [_.times}(https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#times):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="menu">
      {_.times(5, i => (
        <a onClick={this.targetValue} key={i} href="#">{i + 1}</a>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

*Updated: Added `keys` and lodash, thanks @JoshKelly*

Comment: If you're using Lodash, its [times](https://dustinpfister.github.io/2017/10/11/lodash_times/) method would be cleaner than making up a blank array.

Also, don't forget to set the [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) property on your components.

Something like this should work: `{_.times(5, i => <a onClick={this.targetValue} key={i} href="#">{i + 1}</a>)}`.

Comment: Good catch @JoshKelley, thanks.  Also added your `_.times` example.

Comment: Personally I like `Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => i);` `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I've never seen that before, I like it.